# Excel VBA - Copy from multiple sheets with condition and placing in certain cell in different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA Excel and I have some code that will go through multiple sheets and copy values in certain range of cells if the criteria are met.

So basically I would like to copy certain data from multiple sheets and paste it in certain cells (it must be placed based on the variable in the cells)

I would like to copy from sheet 1, 2, 3, etc., cell E to L and place it in another sheet, based on the value of cell L5:
[image: I would like to copy from sheet 1, 2, 3, etc., cell E to L and place it in another sheet, based on the value of cell L5]

And paste it to this sheet, in cell F to M, if the value of cell C in sheet Template 1 are the same with cell L5 in sheet 1,2,3,etc:
[image: And paste it to this sheet, in cell F to M, if the value of cell C in sheet Template 1 are the same with cell L5 in sheet 1,2,3,etc.]

Here are the code that I have:

```
 Option Explicit

'Note: This example use the function LastRow
'This example copy the range A2:G2 from each worksheet.
'
'Change the range here
'
''Fill in the range that you want to copy
'Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A2:G2")

'When you run one of the examples it will first delete the summary worksheet
'named RDBMergeSheet if it exists and then adds a new one to the workbook.
'This ensures that the data is always up to date after you run the code.

'*****READ THE TIPS on the website****

Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Delete the sheet "RDBMergeSheet" if it exist
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'On Error Resume Next
    'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
    'On Error GoTo 0
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Add a worksheet with the name "RDBMergeSheet"
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Template 1")
    'DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"

    'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        'Loop through all worksheets except the RDBMerge worksheet and the
        'Information worksheet, you can ad more sheets to the array if you want.
        If IsError(Application.Match(sh.Name, _
                                     Array("Information", "Template 1", "Template 2", "Template 3"), 0)) Then


            'Find the last row with data on the DestSh
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)

            'Fill in the range that you want to copy
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range("E10:L10")

            'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
            If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
                GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If


            'This example copies values/formats, if you only want to copy the
            'values or want to copy everything look at the example below this macro
            'For i = 2 To LastRow(DestSh)
            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "E")
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

            'Optional: This will copy the sheet name in the H column
            'DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "H").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Name

        End If
    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.GoTo DestSh.Cells(1)

    'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

The code above succeeded to copy from sheet 1,2,3,etc in cell range but place it in the last row and not yet based on the criteria.
I would like to know how to incorporate the criteria that I need to the code above? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code will do for loops which find the sheet where the L5 value matches the C1 value in each of the Templates. Inside that if statement is where you can put the code you have that copies and pastes the values. Good luck!

```
 Sub matchTemplateWithSheet()
 '
 ' matchTemplateWithSheet Macro
 '

 '
 Dim x As Integer
 Dim y As Integer
 Dim a As Integer
 Dim b As Integer
 Dim numberOfTemplates As Integer
 Dim numberOfSheets As Integer

 numberOfTemplates = 3  'you can set the number of templates you're trying to fill
 numberOfSheets = 5      ' you can set the number of sheets you're looking through. _
                        this can also easily be automated in the code

 For x = 1 To numberOfTemplates
     a = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Template " & x).Cells(1, 3)

     For y = 1 To numberOfSheets
         b = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet" & y).Cells(5, 12)

         If a = b Then

             '''''This is where you can put the copy/paste code that you already have'''''

          End If

     Next y

Next x



 End Sub
```